# How does Angular integrate with ASP.NET Core MVC project?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, domain-driven-design

My understanding is that frontend frameworks like Angular, React are separate applications that invoke the Web API built using .NET Core or any other server side technology.

I am now reading that Angular can be integrated with .NET Core and I am confused about this concept. In ASP.NET Core MVC, the MVC layer is the UI project. This layer uses the infrastructure and core layer classes for functionality.

If we replace the UI layer with angular then how will Angular be able to use those infra / core classes? (I am asking because my understanding is that Angular works only with Web APIs).

Answer (score 1):

> how will Angular be able to use those infra / core classes?

Angular does not use anything from .NET

> Angular works only with Web APIs

Once Angular is loaded into the browser it can do what it was supposed to do. It doesn't have to call an API. It may be an offline game, it may be an offline utility, it may wanna work with device sensors, etc.

So normally we have an API that is somewhere on a server and is being served to the world with a webserver (kestrel, nginx, IIS, etc).

We also have a bundle of JavaScript files that are our Angular app and these are just static files that need to be loaded into the client's browser. So we also need a webserver for serving static files (again kestrel, etc).

What ASP.NET Core SPA integration offers (for production) is nothing more than just serving those static files. So instead of creating a new website for serving your Angular static files, ASP.NET Core says I'm already up and running why don't you let me serve those static files as well?

This can have benefits on some cases, for example if the API is only going to serve the Angular app, then they are both on the same domain and you don't need to configure any CORS policy and you can use the ASP.NET Core Identity with the default cookie authentication which is way more simpler than token based authentication. Also if you don't have a dedicated server and you are using a shared hosting service with Plesk or CPanel or something, then you won't need to buy a separate service for the Angular app and you let the ASP.NET Core handle serving the Angular app as well.

Although I have to say the ASP.NET Core [node services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/client-side/spa-services?view=aspnetcore-5.0) middleware has more capabilities, for example you can configure it to render those static Angular files on the server with node (SSR).

Hope this was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

MVC is fully rendered in server,
Angular is front end for API projects.
MVC is mainly used for quick and dirty projects.